# How is the thermal stability of nitric acid related to its structure?

Tags: stability, vsepr-theory

How is the thermal stability of nitric acid related to its planar structure?

In textbooks it is written that nitric acid is unstable at room temperature and decomposes where $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{H3PO4}$ are stable and decompose at much higher temperature.$\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{H3PO4}$ have tetrahedral structures.